# OAuthSignin error when signing in with google account

Tags: google-oauth, next-auth, next.js13

I am using next js 13.4 or later i have set up google authentication and [...nextauth]/route.js code i directed to google sign in page but when i click on sign in button i got error=OAuthSignin

I have set up the .env.local file and also set up the api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js file and also provided the session in my Provider.js file. all is set but when i try to login i get this problem
[OAuthSignIn_Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OABYD.png)

Answer (score 0):

OAuthSignin was occuring due to configuration in my .env file, i have set up the google_clientId and google_secret in https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=next-promptify but i store them in .env.locals file then i was using these credentials in [...nextauth]/route.js file but whenever i use to login with google it shows me this error "error=OAuthSignin" then i change the name of .env.locals to .env and try to login error vanished and i logged in.
if you are getting the same error then set up the credentials in https://console.cloud.google.com and store these clientId and secret in .env file and call them in [...nextauth]/route.js file your error will be vanished and you will be able to login with google or any providers. Thanks